# Function to return percentages in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, formatting, floating-point

I created a function for giving me percentages from two integers.  I want two decimal places in the result.

```
def percent(num1, num2):
    num1 = float(num1)
    num2 = float(num2)
    percentage = '{0:.2f}'.format((num1 / num2 * 100))
    return percentage
```

It works, but I doubt it's very pythonic (since I have no idea what I'm doing)

```
>> print percent(1234, 5678)
21.73
```

Comment: Is there a better way to format to 2 decimal places?  I would prefer to get a float as a result instead of a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3.0 or later, you do not need to explicitly convert your numbers to `float`. This is because the `/` operator *always* does floating point division (the `//` operator does "floor" division).

For older versions of Python (2.2 or later), you can use:

```
from __future__ import division
```

which changes the old meaning of `/` to the above. This makes the operation of `/` more predictable as the result no longer depends on the type of the inputs.

Comment: This has never appeared to be true to me.  I'm using 2.7.  Are you referring to 3?  Removing the float conversion, I get 0.00 as my result.

Comment: I've updated my answer to better reflect reality.

Comment: And I added the 2.7 tag.

Answer (score 4):

You can also get rid of the temporary variable:

```
percentage = '{0:.2f}'.format((num1 / num2 * 100))
return percentage
```

becomes

```
return '{0:.2f}'.format((num1 / num2 * 100))
```

to return a float use:

```
def percentage(a, b):
    return round(a / b * 100, 2)
```